# what does the sentence "to be integrated into the urban skyline..." in this context mean?

Tags: meaning, sentence-meaning

the writer talks about stadium :

the text

"It is likely to be one of the largest and most prominent buildings in the local area, if not the entire town or city. It will need **to be integrated into the urban skyline and, more directly, within the “street-scape” of the immediate neighbourhood**".

words like urban and skyline i know what they mean.. but combining them together confuses me

also, streetscape what does it mean ?

finally, immediate neighbourhood? what is that

it would be help if you tell me what the writer is trying to say after ***"to be integrated into.."***

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this context "skyline" refers to the overall aesthetic of the city in regards to the average height of its buildings.  "Urban" is simply there to tell the reader that it's a bigger city and not a small village or town.

"Streetscape" refers to how the buildings compare in appearance and style to each of their neighbors.

The overall meaning of the sentence is: "This building is bigger and not fitting with the style of the other buildings in the city and especially with those buildings that are closest to it.  The developers will need to do something to make sure that it fits in."